# Dumping hash of arrays to file

Tags: perl

How can dump a hash of arrays to a file?

Each hash keys is the name of a folder and the array is the all of the files listed in the folder.

Here is what I am working on,

```
open OUTFILE, "> output.txt" or die $!;

    foreach my $key (keys %folder_structure) {

    print OUTFILE "$key\n";

    foreach my $line (@{$folder_structure{$key}}) {

        print OUTFILE "$line\n";

        }

    }

    close OUTFILE;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not have any specific requirement for the output format, the simplest way is to use Data::Dumper:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

open OUTFILE, "> output.txt" or die $1;
print OUTFILE Dumper \%folder_structure;
close OUTFILE;
```

**Edit:** As per the comments, `Dumper` is being passed a reference to the hash, not the hash itself.

The Data::Dumper module has some settings to control output, which you can read about on its [CPAN page](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.128/Dumper.pm).

Comment: You must give an hashref as argument to Dumper. `Dumper \%folder_structure`

Comment: You certainly get more understandable output from Data::Dumper if you use a hash reference. But I think you're rather overstating the case to say that you "must" use one.

Comment: @davorg: You're right, I should have said : `You should give ...`. English is not my native language.

Answer (score 1):

The [Storable.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~ams/Storable-2.25/Storable.pm) module, included in the Perl core distribution since v5.8, and also available from CPAN is designed to allow you to 'freeze' and 'thaw' complex datastructures, saving them to a file, and retrieving them later.

```
use Storable;

my %structure = (foo => 1, bar => 3);
store(\%structure, 'output.storable');
```

To retrieve it back to memory:

```
my %structure = %{retrieve('output.storable')};
```

Or perhaps more legibly:

```
my $structure_hashref = retrieve('output.storable');
my %original_structure = %{$structure_hashref};
```